# Cordova - Scan QR Code and open link... not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, hyperlink, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am kind of new at the programming world and I am struggling to make the barcode scanner open a link after you scan it.
Probably something wrong on my end but don't know where.

Here is my barcode controller code (Cordova)

```
app.controller('barcodeController', function( $scope ){

$scope.barcode = {
  'result': '',
  'format': '',
  'cancelled': ''
}

$scope.startScanner = function(){

  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function (result) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.barcode = {
          'result': result.text,
          'format': result.format,
          'cancelled': result.cancelled
        }
        var ref = window.open(barcode.result, '_blank'); //line added, but not opening the QR Code website, actually it scans and do nothing...
      });

    },
    function (error) {

      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);

    }
  );

};

});
```

Comment: When you remote debug, what error do you see?

Comment: Actually it after I scan the QR code it tries to open a link ( file://android_asset/www/barcode.result ).
I think it is not parsing the URL.

Comment: Is it correct to use the code `var ref = window.open('barcode.result', '_blank');`  ?

Comment: No, that's not correct. Why are you trying to 'open' the result? Is it a url? If so, you'd want the real value: window.open(barcode.result, '_blank'); - no quotes around barcode.result.

Comment: Hi @Raymond Camden, thanks, but I have tried here it it didn't work. Yes it is a URL. My code is like this: `    $scope.startScanner = function(){

      cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
          $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.barcode = {
              'result': result.text,
              'format': result.format,
              'cancelled': result.cancelled
            }
  var ref = window.open(barcode.result, '_blank');
          });`

Comment: It is difficult to read in the comment - can you update your main question text?

Comment: @RaymondCamden Sorry about that, I put a comment into the code so you know where I have changed.

Comment: Ok, first, add a console.log in the result handler for the barcode. Dump out result and see if it has anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it to work! As @RaymondCamden said, I have used the console.log and the QR Code Scanner wasn't dumping anything.
I have to create a variable to store the result and use the variable value to open the website.
Thanks @RaymondCamden, your help was super!